# program/script/etc that auto-refreshes a chrome tab until a certain word/phrase/number is found/not found and then it stops

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, browser-addons, browser-tabs

Something I can use to automatically refresh a web-page (with specified time intervals) that searches the page for a certain text and stops refreshing once its found/not found.

I found this script that I can use with tampermonkey;

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
var LookFor = "test"; // Change this to find a different string

if($('body:contains("' + LookFor + '")').length > 0) 
{
    alert("Found: " + LookFor);
}
else
{
    location.reload();
}
});
```

-but it doesn't allow me to specify the time time between each refresh (be it 0.5 seconds or 4 minutes).

If there is a way to do this please let me know, I am a noob at scripting and stuff so any help will be greatly appreciated ;;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this modified version:

```
$(document).ready(function()  {
  var LookFor = "test"; // Change this to find a different string
  var interval = 5;     // timeout in seconds

  var intervalHandle = setInterval(function () {    
    if($('body:contains("' + LookFor + '")').length > 0) {
      clearInterval(intervalHandle);
      alert("Found: " + LookFor);
    }
  }, interval * 1000);
});
```